# Using nohup for Node.js on Amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nohup, forever

I am trying to get my Node app running reliably from an amazon ec2 instance. I have tried:

1. to install forever I get a ton of errors:

   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT,
   ...
   50 lines of errors
   ...
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:96:15)
2. nohup node server.js &

Method 2 works but it doesn't start my app again if it goes down. Can someone show me how to use nohup to also restart the app if it goes down?
Thanks!

Comment: What OS is your ec2 slice running?

Comment: See this https://gist.github.com/tinogomes/447191. You can modify it to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try with supervisor:

https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor

Quite simple, if something goes wrong it just restart.

For a more complex control, including server restart you can try pm2

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

pm2 is amazing!!

Comment: Thanks node-supervisor worked, didn't need anything fancy, just auto restart